# Discouraging the use of resources linked by the OP?

Tags: discussion, answers

It is no secret that some resources one can find on the Internet are straight up wrong. From time to time the person asking the question will state they are trying out a code sample from somewhere and give the link. Inevitably in certain cases they do link to such a defective resource.

What is one supposed to do now?

The particular case I have in mind is here: [perror() or own string output to stderr in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35597231/perror-or-own-string-output-to-stderr-in-c/35597352#35597352)

Here the OP linked a particularly bad site which I promptly noted, maybe in a manner which was less kind than needed. This prompted an interesting backlash. Currently the answer sits at 2 upvotes and 4 downvotes.

In the comments you can see people arguing the question is opinion based and should not be answered. Ignoring this part, you will see arguing against claiming that the linked site is a bad resource, regardless of validity of said claim.

That said, can I get a short flowchart what to do when OP links a defective resource? I thought saying it is bad and recommending a better one is the natural reaction, but apparently that's not welcome. Note that just recommending something else does not cut it, as the OP may see no incentive to switch.

As a side note, one can't help but note that other "opinionated" answers did not get any backlash nor comments they don't belong.

Answer (score 5):

Whatever you do, don't focus on the "bad resource" as you did. You have effectively destroyed whatever you had going on as an answer to the question asked.

If you want to comment on something ... use comments. The current state of your answer is so entirely focused on the site and later justification of your statement about it, that I actually glanced over what your answer to the question was.

Your job in the answer is to answer the question. If I read an answer, I should not have to fish it out of whatever else you decided to put in there.

Comment: It is easy to see how the state is a side effect of the weird discussion I got in the comments to my answer. In particular, originally there was only a short mention that the site must be avoided. Here, I created this thread so that hopefully this kind of problem is prevented in the future. So, what about the actual question asked which is: what to do with the defective resources linked by OP? Are you saying making a comment discouraging the use of the resource is fine?

Comment: If you find the used resource particularly worrisome, a comment should be enough to state so. But don't let it devolve into an extended discussion about the resource. Take that stuff to chat.

Answer (score 1):

You can expect a downvote if you negatively reference a site loved by someone; even if the site really is bad. If anything because it is basically you voicing a personal opinion, people can easily feel justified in the downvote. But it might also just be revenge.

Perhaps stick to disputing the actual content in question from the site that is terrible and leave it neutral if the site itself is terrible or not and for the readers to discover themselves; that makes it far easier to build an on-topic answer around it that people can easily digest.

Let me put it differently: it is quite hard to factually prove that an entire site is terrible, there will always be good bits of content that disprove it. So just don't go there, stick to what you can easily factually prove right there and then in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was one of the people who criticised your answer in the comments at the time.

The problem is, your answer is focused on your rant against tutorialspoint rather than on the question itself.

You should be adressing the question mainly in an answer, and keep comments on the usefulness of the site used to, well, the comments. (Or maybe a small section of your answer)